# OpenSMTPD Configuration Problem

Tags: email, openbsd, smtp

I'm trying to configure a simple mail server on OpenBSD 5.2, running OpenSMTPD 5.3.1, however there is some problem with my configuration file, and I'm unsure how to fix it. I can send and receive local mail on the computer, but I cannot send external mail from the computer, nor receive it. The following is my `smtpd.conf` And yes, "mydomain.com" is a real domain, that's just a filler.

```
listen on lo0
listen on bce0

table aliases db:/etc/mail/aliases.db

# accept local mail
accept from local for local deliver to mbox

# accept remote mail
accept from any for domain "mydomain.com" deliver to mbox

# allow remote delivery of mail
accept from local for any relay
```

Perhaps it's not doing what I think it is, but any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration file is OK except you're missing a reference to the aliases table in your accept rules:

```
accept from any for domain mydomain.com alias <aliases> deliver to mbox
```

You can run with `smtpd -dv -T smtp` to get incoming session tracing and see where it fails ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I appreciate it. As I figured out from the mailing lists, it's some sort of MX issue that I'm trying to figure out at the moment. It wasn't actually a problem with OpenSMTPD :)